# How to skip span element using jQuery next function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel which has to be like this

```
<button class="next">Next</button>
<span>Test</span>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
```

I need to target the dynamically added `.prev` by using jQuery `next()` function but looks like span is bugging this selection?

How can I skip the `span` here?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".next", function() {
  $(this).next(".prev").addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<span>Test</span>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: If you know the span is always there, you could just do next().next('.prev') .  The selector for the next operates as a filter.  It doesn't make it go next until it finds a match.  It filters out the next one if it does not match.

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the positional based logic of your issue, I would suggest you encapsulate your elements and use `parent()` or `closest()` and perform a contextual lookup rather than using next() or prev().

```js
$(document).on("click", ".next", function() {
  $(this).closest('.navigation-wrapper').find('.prev').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="navigation-wrapper">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <span>Test</span>
  <button class="prev">Prev</button>
</span>
```

Using logic like this, you don't care if there is a span, or where it is.  You **know** that the prev belongs to the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nextAll(".prev")` to get all siblings of that class (`.next()` only fetches the immediate sibling), then isolate the first of that type with `.eq(0)`

Like in this snippet!

```js
$(document).on("click", ".next", function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".prev").eq(0).addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<span>Test</span>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: Again, this answer seems to accomplish exactly what OP requested, yet has also received a downvote with no explanation :/

Comment: I dv your answer, and uv your comment.  The code, while answer the question explicity, is also *extremely fragile* in that it relies on the order of HTML for the functionality to work.  For example, wrapping buttons causes your code not to work. See my comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) only checks the next element. If you include a selector, it either returns the next element *if it matches*, or *nothing*.

Consider using [`.siblings(".prev")`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) (all siblings with class `prev`) combined with [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) (the first one only).

```js
$(document).on("click", ".next", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".prev").first().addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="next">Next</button>
<span>Test</span>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
```